# Mongoid: blank belongs_to association

Tags: ruby, associations, mongoid

I have belongs_to :provider in my model, and provider_id is set, but association is still blank:

```
irb(main):095:0> o2.provider_id
=> BSON::ObjectId('4e0472f36d40ec0004000001')
irb(main):096:0> o2.provider
=> nil
```

Also, model has provider_id= method with "write_attribute(:provider_id, provider_id)" inside.

What could be wrong here?

Mongoid version is 2.4.0

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check that there exists a record in `Provider` collection with the ID??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a `has_one` or `has_many` association in your other model.

```
 class Foo
   include Mongoid::Document
   belongs_to :bar
 end

 class Bar
   include Mongoid::Document
   has_one :foo
 end
```

Comment: There is :has_many in the Provider model. All my experience with ActiveRecord says this code should work, but in Mongoid it does not :( So I'm using Provider.find(o.provider_id)

Comment: I'm doing exactly this with mongoid and it works like a charm. Good luck.

Comment: Wait, `has_many `? Then it will return an array of providers. Try `o2.providers`